# how to combine Opencv module (virtualenvwrapper) and Tensorflow module (another virtualenv)?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, virtualenvwrapper

Following several instructions on the web, I could install `Opencv3.0` and `tensorflow` on my Ubuntu 16.04. Each tutorial recommends using virtual environment. Although I agree that, problem is that I just followed the tutorials and created separate environments.

** For minor information, Tensorflow installation was easy, but Opencv3.0 was hard.

I used `virtualenv` for Tensorflow with the name `tf`, and `virtualenvwrapper` for Opencv with the name `cv`, i.e., I activate `tf` by `$ source ~/project/tf/bin/activate`, and `cv` by `$ workon cv`.

In this case, what is the best way of using both? 
Should I activate both always?
Should I enter one environment and install the other again?
Should I symlink `site-package/cv.so` to `tf` environment?

I think `cv` is now in the python `site-package` folder. I create `tf` with `--site-package` option, but it was before installing `cv`. I am so confusing. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I had the same issue and the sym-link between tensorflow and openCV will not work after making the cv.so inside the tf virtualenv after some struggle I got them both to work in the same environment but I suggest uninstalling openCV and then install it back without using a virtual environment for better results.

Cheers.